# PhD application: Responses from a few professors, but no conversion

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path

I am looking for a PhD in Computer Vision, Human-Robot Interaction (HRI).

The core of this question is to understand how do the following factors affect an application:

- Acceptable study gap. Do personal reasons for study gap have any credibility?
- Percentage that is considered 'excellent'. Does it differ across countries?
- Good industry experience but not aligned to the area of interest for research
- Old research paper (theses included), say 5 years
- No academic reference, but references from highly positioned people in the industry, say a CTO or VP

Though getting replies from professors on personalized emails does not guarantee an admit, what factors must be hindering the acceptance?

Additionally, could Research Assistant position be the right way forward? Or should it be via another masters?

Let know if more information is needed.

Edit:
I am based in India and targeting European universities primarily. Recently started exploring Asian universities as well.

Comment: Have you actually made formal applications or just sent emails?

Comment: @astronat Emails followed by formal applications.

Comment: do you have thesis in MSc?

Comment: @yahoo.com Yes, the publication revolves around the same.

Comment: a final query before posting my answer: which countries did you apply to?

Comment: @yahoo.com Germany, Switzerland, UK, Austria, Portugal, Romania, Hong Kong (just last Sat.). Got replies from profs at leading universities one each in Germany, UK, and Switzerland. Reading papers from professors in other neighboring countries as well. Do you need access to my paper and thesis as well?

Comment: Has the decision periods for all of your applications already expired?

Comment: A few are pending. Two in Sweden, HongKong one as well could be termed as pending. Prepping to apply in Belgium, Luxembourg, Italy, and Norway. Missed to add Finland to the list of applied ones.

Comment: Note that we won't evaluate your application material or credentials, and outside of that it's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: @xLeitix Yes, the first question would be around credentials expectations at leading universities. Beyond that, if profs find my first email credible enough to reply, what all factors might hinder the acceptance of my application? Could it be a missing academic reference, or no association with the field for a good number of years. Credibility of the conference I published at? Or simply my research statement or letter or motivation. Could it be anything more beyond that?

Comment: @SumitSrivastava, Okay. Given that the question is closed now, I can only write in the comment section. The issue I am finding is the **study-gap**. You completed your MSc in 2012 which is 6 years ago, and you didn't publish papers on a regular basis either, which shows that you are not motivated to do **research**. The solution is not very simple. In case of Europe, you have to enter another MSc program. You can do a thesis, and then either complete the MSc degree or directly get admission in a PhD program by requesting the supervisor.

Comment: @SumitSrivastava, Another minor point is, you have produced non-academic references which is detrimental to getting an acceptance. Work on that also. Good luck!

Comment: @yahoo.com This is really helpful. Gives the direction to focus my efforts upon. Thanks.

Comment: @yahoo.com Another question related to it. Would research assistant be a good option in this case? Do European universities accept applications for such positions from international students?

Comment: @SumitSrivastava, it depends on the university. Apart from UK very few universities pay money to PhD students. In that case China or Hong Kong would be better.